# Group WebMethods in WebService

Tags: java, visual-studio, wsdl, webmethod

I've got question because I didn't find any answer in all internet.

I'm using *Wildfly 8.2.0* and *JaxWS WebService* by *Netbeans 8.0.2*, and i'm importing this *WSDL* output to VisualStudio as Service Reference. I know it's maybe not the best way to do WebAPI but but...

Everything's work great except that all WebMethods are in one place. I've got *VisualStudio Client()* and structure is *Client().AllFunctionsHere*.
Can I somehow group WebMethods which as result I will get `Client().Login.Auth(), Client().Register.AddNew(), Client().Register.ComparePasswords()` etc...

It's theoretically very valuable but I couldn't find solution.

P.S.: I don't want to create few WebServices because I've got "Login" method and a few WebServices don't share session unfortunatelly.

Comment: Given how the client code is usually generated code, I think to get the sort of api functionality you will need to create a wrapper around the Client code that will give you the behaviour you are after.

Comment: @user3465651 that's right! I didn't think about it. I wrote class that contains structs and calls methods from Web Service. That's not best resolving because it's work only for C# but it's work. It's enough for now. Thanks.